# Aparent right characters creating problems with sql queries

Tags: sql

Ok this is odd.

I was trying to find nirvana in my database, but for some reason sql missed some entries.

[Check this Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7406da5cdf4c22fc1525d1d629e9abc)

As you can see, Nirvana is equal in both queries but the result are not the same.

One thing i've noticed in note++ is the word nirvana seems not equal in some way and seems the problem are in the "a" letters.. as you can see, it looks identical, but something is not the same and sql detects that difference creating the issue.

Any clue how to avoid this witchcraft??

Comment: yes, there is a special character 'а' in your data and also in your first select statement. And the character is CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER а

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is some diff b/w the characters,

You can try out skipping "a" letter.

i.e

```
select * from test where test.Title like '%nirv%n%'
```

or

```
select * from test where test.Title like '%nirv_n_%'
```

Comment: This is a solution for this particular case, but i think a real solution could be some way to standardize the characters on the database. Somehow someone was able to store weird characters on the database and its impossible to the naked eye to find if its wrong or right. and i guess there are more errors like this one on the db.

Answer (score 0):

So far I found, you can create a function to translate all CYRILLIC LETTER and use this function in your where condition. https://github.com/igstan/sql-utils/blob/master/transliterate.sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION `transfunc`(original VARCHAR(512)) RETURNS varchar(512) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
 
DECLARE translit VARCHAR(512) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE len INT(3) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pos INT(3) DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE letter CHAR(4);
 
SET original = TRIM(LOWER(original));
SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(original);
 
WHILE (pos <= len) DO
SET letter = SUBSTRING(original, pos, 1);
 
CASE TRUE
 
WHEN letter IN('á','à','â','ä','å','a','a','a','?','?') THEN SET letter = 'a';
WHEN letter IN('c','c','ç','c') THEN SET letter = 'c';
WHEN letter IN('d','d','?','?') THEN SET letter = 'd';
WHEN letter IN('é','e','ë','è','ê','e','e','?','?') THEN SET letter = 'e';
WHEN letter IN('g','g') THEN SET letter = 'g';
WHEN letter IN('í','î','ï','i','î','?','?') THEN SET letter = 'i';
WHEN letter IN('k') THEN SET letter = 'k';
WHEN letter IN('l','l','l','l') THEN SET letter = 'l';
WHEN letter IN('n','n','n','ñ') THEN SET letter = 'n';
WHEN letter IN('ó','ö','ø','õ','ô','o','o','?','?') THEN SET letter = 'o';
WHEN letter IN('r','r','?','?') THEN SET letter = 'r';
WHEN letter IN('š','s','?','s','?','?') THEN SET letter = 's';
WHEN letter IN('t','?') THEN SET letter = 't';
WHEN letter IN('ú','u','ü','ù','û','u','u','u') THEN SET letter = 'u';
WHEN letter IN('ý','?','?') THEN SET letter = 'y';
WHEN letter IN('ž','z','z') THEN SET letter = 'z';
 
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'b';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'v';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'g';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'd';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'zh';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'z';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'i';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'i';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'k';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'l';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'm';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'n';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'p';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 't';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'f';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'ch';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'c';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'ch';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'sh';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'shch';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = '';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'y';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'e';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'ju';
WHEN letter = '?' THEN SET letter = 'ja';
 
WHEN letter IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','y','z')
OR letter REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
THEN SET letter = letter;

ELSE
SET letter = '-';
 
END CASE;
 
SET translit = CONCAT(translit, letter);
SET pos = pos + 1;
END WHILE;
 
WHILE (translit REGEXP '\-{2,}') DO
SET translit = REPLACE(translit, '--', '-');
END WHILE;
 
RETURN TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM translit);
 
END
```

And then use function in the query with default character 'nirvana'. Not use CYRILLIC LETTER in the query

```
select * from test where transfunc(test.Title) like '%nirvana%'
```